# STS - Gradle - Java Home is different

Tags: java, gradle, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Today I turn on my laptop and STS shows me this error, and I dont have any idea, Why STS is raising this.

[image]

My java home is :

[image]

and my gradle project is using java 1.7.

Maybe you can help me to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have multiple JDK versions installed in your \Java directory?

Comment: Yes I Have, Java 6, 7 and 8. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be related to having multiple jdk installs and can be fixed by renaming the other jdk folders, however the true problem here may be caused by a symlink in /jdk1.8.0_71/jre/lib/tools.jar pointing to jdk/1.8.0_71/lib/tools.jar. Remove the symlink and see if Gradle works.

Comment: maybe this could be the solution I remember I copied this jar to this folder, but I have remove my other JDK versions and just installed one version. and this solved my problem. But I am sure the solution you mentioned is right. Thank you.